# Maven Error spring-data-neo4j-rest-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar; cannot read zip file maven error

Tags: maven, maven-3, spring-data-neo4j

I have been facing with below maven build error since morning today, [ERROR]  error reading /Users/Surya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j-rest/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-data-neo4j-rest-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar; cannot read zip file

I have manually got the jar file and tried deleting the complete maven repository but still couldn't resolve it.
Everything was going great till yesterday and have not made any changes since morning.

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to resolve this issues?

Am using following repository,

```xml
<repository>
<id>spring-maven-snapshot</id>
<name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
<url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

When i tried to replace with/add following one, it gives me other errors,

```xml
<repository>
 <id>spring-snapshot</id>
 <name>Spring Maven SNAPSHOT Repository</name>
 <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

Other errors:Could not resolve dependencies for project org.netvogue.server:netvogue-database-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2-beta1 from/to spring-snapshot (http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot): Access denied to: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2-beta1/httpclient-4.2-beta1.jar -> [Help 1]

Comment: Sitting behind a proxy ? Firewall ?

Comment: nope. It was working fine till yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: It worked like champ. Could you please let me know the difference between RC1 and Build-Snapshot?